# Cannot get correct privileges using Samba on NFS mounted partition

Tags: server, samba, nfs

I have read/scanned for Samba/NFS problems and answers on the forum, which were quite interesting, many thanks for those :) Setting up NFS can be quite a pain in the ... but getting a warning before the problems arise is really a nice thing to have.

My problem:
I installed two PC's with Ubuntu/Kubuntu, both as server, but need some help getting things right. Ubuntu is working fine, on both machines (called P and N), and I installed Samba on machine P to make an easy interface with all the Windows machines in the office, and installed NFS client on the same machine P. The other machine N is setup with NFS server.

Everything is working fine, Windows shows the Samba user home directory, logs in fine on machine P, and the NFS mount is also visible, and when I use a linux shell to login on a linux account, I can see the NFS mounted directory, and I am able to write to it (create new files).

What is working:
  A Samba user can read files on the NFS mount, and can even rename files on it.
What is not working:
  A Samba user cannot create a new file.

I synchronized the GUID/UID on both machines as to not fall into the NFS users pitfall, so that cannot be the problem. At this moment I don't have that many users installed, so it's easy to keep track.

It might well be that my problem is version related: Machine P runs 12.04 Ubuntu, machine N runs 12.10 (Kubuntu). And I am using PuTTY to get a shell

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to browse the internet for more details (as I am just passing by), but the issue is due to file locking--specifically opportunistic locking not playing well with NFS. You can tell Samba that the Linux kernel (or really NFS in this case) doesn't support opportunistic locking by adding the following to the smb.conf file:

```
kernel oplocks = no
```

There are drawbacks to this approach, but it's the quickest and easiest resolution I know of.

It's been a year since you asked the question, so I hope you haven't STILL been waiting for an answer but I hope that this ends up helping someone else!

Cheers,

polymathcoder